# How to disable parameter name hints in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way to disable the hints?

[image: Parameter hints]

Comment: right-click....

Comment: such an awful thing hu?

Comment: Love the arrows. How do I turn those on?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A bit of general info on parameter names hints can be found in this official introduction blog post: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/new-in-phpstorm-2017-1-parameter-hints/

---

**Now back to the actual question:**

NOTE: It's all working **since 2017.1 version**

Either right click on such parameter and choose appropriate action from the menu

[image]

or go via Settings/Preferences directly:

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Appearance --> Show parameter names hints`

[image]

**In latest 2019.3** version this option is now located at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints` where you can configure that on per supported language basis:

[image]

---

If you wish to customize colors used to display such hints (especially viable for custom color schemes that use dark background colors) then please do it at

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts | Language Defaults`
3. `Inline parameter hints` node.

[image]

Comment: Any way to modify parameter hint's font size? It's twice the size of my param's value :/

Comment: @pambuk Screenshot of the issue is welcome; as well as info on IDE version/OS used. AFAIK -- No ... as whole editor uses single reference to the font size (defined in `Font` section) and in some places just uses "10% smaller" or alike hardcoded sizing. If it's "twice the size" .. then it must be a bug (and you have HiDPI monitor and possibly non-standard scaling/density). Do you have similar issues in other parts of the IDE interface (font is too small/too little space between elements/etc)?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JzlC3WK.png

IDE 2017.2.4, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, I'm using Inconsolata font (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/inconsolata).

Comment: @pambuk It might be Linux or font specific issue. The best solution for now -- file a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and provide this screenshot and your idea.log (which will tell versions and other needed stuff). I could not find an existing ticket that would match your issue myself.

Comment: Thank you. What I found out was that it's actually caused by not-monospaced font, monospaced fonts look correct.

Comment: Any way to turn parameter hint off in part of a source file, similar to `@formatter:off`?

Comment: @Pang No. Only for certain functions/methods .. or completely.

Answer (score 4):

Put your cursor on the hint, and click `Alt + Enter` on Windows, `Option + Enter` on a Mac, or right-click on any platform.

[image: Do not show hints for current method]

If you want to manually blacklist methods, open `Preferences -> Appearance -> Show parameter hint names -> Configure` and then add the one you want hidden to the list:

```
com.myapp.package.MyClass.myMethod(parameterName)
```

This uses pattern matching, you can replace parameterName with a * to match all overloads or put it somewhere else to match a wider range of methods.