# PhpStorm Ellipsis Popup is Hiding Text Input

Tags: editor, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2018.1. I am not sure what this ellipsis popup is for and when it comes up it hides what I am typing behind it. Is there any way to disable it?

[image: Ellipsis Image]

Comment: Not sure (not NodeJS user) ... but at first glance it looks like Parameter Name hint (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743975/783119). You entering parameters for `path.join()` method ... that (as I understand) may (not fixed number) parameters .. so `...` might be used as such "hint".

Comment: @LazyOne yea just seems like a bug. It’s the only popup that displays itself over the text that I’m typing.

Comment: File a ticket to JetBrains Issue Tracker then - they will tell for sure. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB -- WebStorm -- home project for JS stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, [WEB-14542](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14542).
As a workaround, please try disabling **Show the parameter info popup** in **Settings | Editor | General | Code completion**