# Where to change the colors of a function's parameter hints for WebStorm / PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, config, color-scheme

PhpStorm 2018.1.3 offers the feature to name function parameters.

If you have a function `describe` having the arguments `description` and `callback` and you call it via:

```
 describe("Csv Task", async () => { ... })
```

it will show as:

[image: Screenshot of phpstorm's rendering of the colored parameter hints.]

I dislike the hard readability and stark contrast with the dark theme of the dark gray font on the light gray background. Yet I couldn't find where to change these colors in PhpStorm.

How to change the colors of the parameter hints?

Comment: It's called "parameter name hints". Searching for `name hints` in the Settings/Preferences locates appropriate settings pages. Do you want to just change colors ... or disable it completely (or for some functions only)? In any case -- this one has it all (for an older version, but it's still accurate for 2018.1 as well, where you may see one ore style to configure): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743975/783119

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the colors in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults**, **Inline parameter hints**:

[image]