# Laravel 6 version using compact

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-6

What does Laravel 6 version using a

```
return view(view: 'index', data: compact(varname: 'string'));
```

I was following a tutorial, but the one I downloaded it seems it's different codes on the tutorial and always gets me an error. I downloaded a Laravel 6.11.0 version. I'm a beginner on this framework hope there's someone could understand and I want to learn about this laravel framework.

here is the tutorial link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98ChVWjI6KI&list=PLpzy7FIRqpGC8Jk6gyWdSVdxCVXZAsenQ&index=5

Answer (score 2):

You should just use:

```
return view('index', compact('string'));
```

Those `view:`, `data:` and `varname:` are parameter name hints from PHPStorm IDE and not the actual code.

Comment: "Parameter name hints" is a better name. If someone wants to disable or customize them -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743975/783119