# Strange visual wrapping of spread argument in WebStorm with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

This is only a visual issue.

The `...rest` argument gets wrapped in 3 different lines in WebStorm with TypeScript.

This is a sample of the code :

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { MarkerProps } from 'react-native-maps';

export interface ITeddyMarkerDraggable extends MarkerProps {
}

const TeddyMarkerDraggable: FC<ITeddyMarkerDraggable> = ({
  props,
  ...rest,
}) => <View />;

export default TeddyMarkerDraggable;
```

and a picture to illustrate the issue:
[image]

What do the grey arrows represent and which setting could I play around to help with the issue?

Comment: *"What do the grey arrows represent"* That is **soft wraps**. It is used to fit long line on a screen by virtually splitting into separate lines to prevent horizontal scrolling (as you may see you have no line numbers between 10 and 11 in the gutter). You can disable that for current file via `View | Active Editor` menu (or gutter area context menu). For default on/off toggle -- just use search field in the Settings/Preferences window.

Comment: Thanks! I have just noticed that disabling Soft wraps fixes the issue. I also opened a ticket in the JetBrains support. Not sure if it is an issue...

Comment: The actual reason for such wrapping here must the the super long parameter name hint (that `:Pick<ITeddyMarkerDraggable & {children?: ReactNode},....`) -- if you prefer, you may disable that one instead. It's called "Inlay hints" in current version -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743975/783119). Not sure why it's so long and if it's a bug or what -- I'm not using TypeScript myself and not familiar with IDE tickets in that area)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43954 -- seems related. Please try 2020.1 Beta / EAP build (you can run it alongside with current version -- IDE wide settings are stored separately) -- it should work better there. https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/

Comment: I have tried the 2020.1 Beta. It does fold by default very long "Inlay hints". When unfolding the strange formatting still appears when the window is not wide enough and you can't fold again the hint. In the end this is not a real issue I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Submitted to developers, please follow [WEB-44657](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44657) for updates